# Not able to execute the code for ZooKeeperMetaDataStore

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I am using spring integration where I am trying to create a bean for MetaData

```
    @Bean
    public MetadataStore zkStore(CuratorFramework client) {
        return new ZookeeperMetadataStore(client);
    }
```

I am getting the error

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'zkStore'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.getListenable()'
```

After dig down further I found class PathChildrenCache is deprecated and replaced by Interface. Is there any way I can run this piece of code.

dependencies used by project

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
                    <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` means that you have incompatible classpath.

Spring Integration is based on the Curator `4.3.0`. So, better to revise your dependencies in whatever would make it working.

We have an opened issue to move to Curator `5.1` (or higher), but since there are enough breaking changes with their new API, we can't do that immediately: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3435